# Max array sum of non-adjacent elements using DP

Tags: c++, bottom-up

This is a popular problem with DP. I have to find the maximum sum in an array which is formed by non-adjacent elements only. I saw other posts but I want to do this using dynamic programming, in particular, bottom-up DP. Here is my code:

```
int maxSubsetSum(vector<int> arr,int start,int end) {
    int sum[arr.size()]; //to store max sum upto a given index
    sum[0] = arr[start];
    sum[1] = max(arr[start], arr[end]);
    if(start==end){
      return sum[0];
    }
    else if(start==end-1){
      return sum[1];
    }
    else{
        for(int i=2;i<=end;i++){
            sum[i]=max(arr[i],max(arr[i]+sum[i-2],sum[i-1]));
        }
    }
    return sum[end];
}
```

I am running into errors passing the test cases. Although when I ran one test case by hand it worked out correctly. The actual output was the same as what I had obtained. But the testing system gave a different output to my code.

I tested this code by hand on test case: 3 5 -7 8 10
and the answer matched the actual output (=15) but test case did not pass.

```
sum[0]=3
sum[1]=5
sum[2]=max(-7,max(-7+3,5))=5
sum[3]=max(8,max(8+5,5))=13
sum[4]=max(10,max(10+5,13))=15
```

Please point me in the right direction where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you add description of the original problem? It might be popular, but i've never heard of it.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski Here is the link to the original problem: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/max-array-sum/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dynamic-programming

Comment: There's no recursion in your code, so something is wrong for sure (disregard that comment - i'm wrong).

Comment: @RadosławCybulski I have specifically mentioned in the question that I want to do this using bottom-up DP so there will be no recursion. Recursion led to time limit exceeded.

Comment: Yes, i just noticed it. This is C++, right?

Comment: @RadosławCybulski Yes, C++

Comment: original problem doesn't have start and end parameters, what are those? On top of this you'll overflow your array `sum` for problem of size 1 (`sum[1]` won't exist).

Comment: @RadosławCybulski I have declared sum array to be equal to size of original array. I have set start and end parameters in my solution's main() to be equal to 0 and arr.size()-1

Comment: assuming end points to the last element `sum[1] = max(arr[start], arr[end])` will propagate 10 into `sum[1]`, which will add to the end value and produce 20 instead of 15.

Comment: @RadosławCybulski That did it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
int maxSubsetSum(vector<int> arr) {
    if (arr.size() == 1) {
      return arr[0];
    }
    if (arr.size() == 2) {
      return max(arr[0], arr[1]);
    }
    int sum[arr.size()]; //to store max sum upto a given index
    sum[0] = arr[0];
    sum[1] = max(arr[0], arr[1]);
    for(int i = 2; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        sum[i] = max(arr[i], max(arr[i] + sum[i - 2], sum[i - 1]));
    }
    return sum[arr.size() - 1];
}
```

Comment: It seems not necessary, but if you change the signature of the function to `int maxSubsetSum(vector<int>& arr)` and notice, that simultaneously you need only three members of `sum` (that's `sum[i]`, `sum[i - 1]` and `sum[i - 2]`) additional memory usage can be `O(1)`.

Comment: I haven't even thought of that - i fixated on trying to find a bug, not on improving. You're correct, although your option would mess up the code. ;) Kudos to you, dear sir.